# Implement a base class in widget class Flutter

Tags: flutter, widget, stateful

I want widget classes implemented from a base class to force them implement a specific method.

Base class:

```
class Test {
  bool check() {
    return false;
   }
 }
```

Then other widgets should implement `Test` regardless they are Stateful or Stateless.

```
class TestWidget1 extends StatelessWidget implements Test{
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    ...
  }

 @override
 bool check(bool checkAnswer) {
    return true;
 }
}
```

So I can use the widgets like below example and be sure they all have implemented `check` method:

```
Test test1 = TestWidget1();
final bool result = test1.check();
```

But what about Stateful widgets? I need to implement `Test` class in the widget class of a Stateful widget so I can access to the `check` method outside of the widget class. But I don't have access to the state's variables:

```
class TestWidget2 extends StatefulWidget implements Test {
  @override
  _TestWidget2State createState() => _TestWidget2State();

  @override
  bool check(bool checkAnswer) {
    // TODO: implement check
  }
}

class _TestWidget2State extends State<TestWidget2> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container();
  }
}
```

And if I implement `Test` in `_TestWidget2State` the `Test` is no longer the parent of `TestWidget2`  widget.

How can I solve this problem? Is there a better solution to implement a class by a widget regardless of its type (Stateful/Stateless)?

Answer (score 0):

Create a separate class rather than creating a widget.

```
class SampleClass implements Test {

 @override
 bool check(bool checkAnswer) {
    return true;
 }
}
```

---

Calling...

```
Test sample = SampleClass();
final bool result = sample.check();
```

Comment: Thanks. I know how to implement Test class in a simple class but I need to use widgets because there is a ui and the check method checks the user inputs in a textField for example. Then the parent widget call each child check method to know they results.

Comment: @RShpd: You have to move your logic to Sample Class, and based on that return result, if required create more methods. Hope it will help you.

Comment: Sorry, the answer didn't help me to solve the problem.